# One form element updating multiple pieces of the model?

Tags: angularjs

I am looking at using angular for a project at work but I have a question first. We have a single page application that's pretty intricate. We do have a basic model set up but some fields in the model are redundant. If I couldn't reduce the redundancy, what steps could I take in angular so that one form element changes two variables in the model?

I've put together a bare bones [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/coreyog/g3bz5/) of what I'm hoping to do:

```
<div ng-app>
    <input type="text" ng-model="yourName" placeholder="Enter a name here" /><br/>
    <span>Hello {{yourName}}!</span><br/>
    <span>Hello {{altName}}!</span>
</div>
```

How could I change this around so that the input would assign it's value to both `yourName` as well as `altName`? I've tried what I thought would be obvious such as comma or pipe delimiting the `ng-model` attribute to no avail. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set a `$watch` on the `yourname`-Variable within your controller and then change the `altName` in its callback. Should look like this:

```
 $scope.$watch('yourName', function(){
      $scope.altName = $scope.newName;
 });
```

Comment: That's actually a lot easier than I thought.

Comment: Also, for the record, having 2 variables watching each other seems to be ok. Changing either one will update both.

Comment: I would recommend to keep the number of `$watch`es as low as possible, as it can have a negative impact on performance in larger apps. But yep, its possible ;)